# Quiero que en un textbox me muestre un string que tengo almacenado de un evento keydown

Tags: c#

tengo esa variable guardada en el evento keydown que me guarda el nombre de la tecla que presiono.
Puse en comentario para que me lo muestre en un messagebox ,pero yo quiero que me lo muestre en el mismo    textbox, no se como hacerlo.
Saludos.

[image: Mi codigo]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como le mandas texto a cualquier textbox?

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo el sentido de lo que pretendes; pero se puede lograr así:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = keyPressed;
}

string keyPressed;  // La declaramos aquí ya que se usa en TextChange y en KeyDown
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeysConverter convertor = new KeysConverter();
    keyPressed = convertor.ConvertToString(e.KeyValue);
    textBox1.Text = keyPressed;
}
```

Comment: Ahora si!! muchas gracias! habia echo todo eso antes pero me faltaba declar la variable afuera por eso no me andaba!. Gracias por el comentario ese que hiciste que me hizo dar cuenta!